# Vanilla JS Async not working on Heroku Flask Web App

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, heroku

Made a Flask web app with a basic JS function that act as a timer after the user submit the button.

It works perfectly fine locally but once deployed to Heroku, the async function does not work, and Heroku returns an overtime error 503 (since as expected the python script that the app is calling is requiring more that 1 min to run, and heroku has the timeout limit triggered then).

This is the error I am getting from Logs:

```
2021-06-26T14:19:24.650542+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.168.144 - - [26/Jun/2021 14:19:24] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
2021-06-26T14:19:57.520038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/" host=python-url-crawler.herokuapp.com request_id=3dacf2e6-3873-4997-85db-aa747780b0f2 fwd="93.38.66.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Consider that the web app is otherwise perfectly working, but I need to display a message in the html main page as soon as the user click submit, and this is not working (so I am assuming that the issue is in something missing from the async)

My Procfile:

```
web: python main_app.py
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "url-crawler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this is just to start the JS function (supposedly).",
  "main": "/static/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }, 
  
  "engines": { 
    "node": "7.10.0",
    "npm": "4.2.0"
  },
  
  "author": "carlo-occhiena",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

My requirements.txt

```
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.4
gunicorn==20.0.4
Jinja2==2.11.2
json5==0.9.1
lxml==4.2.1
requests==2.25.1
stop_words==2018.7.23
```

My tree:

```
\static
   -main.js
   -mystyle.css
\templates
   -main.html
Procfile
main_app.py
package.json
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

This is my async func:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  
  async function stamp() {
    document.getElementById("stamp1").innerHTML = "Process started...";
    await sleep(10000);
    document.getElementById("stamp2").innerHTML = "...we're going, please hold. 10 sec. passed.";
    await sleep(10000);
    document.getElementById("stamp3").innerHTML = "...script running. 20 sec passed.";
    await sleep(10000);
    document.getElementById("stamp4").innerHTML = "...script running. 30 sec passed.";

  }
```

The function is called once user click submit from main.html:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Scan!" onclick = "stamp()" /></p>
```

And finally this is the html section where i am expecting to see the value printed by the js function:

```
    <p><input type="submit" value="Scan!" onclick = "stamp()" /></p>
        </form>

        <div id="stamp">
            <p id="stamp1"></p>
            <p id="stamp2"></p>
            <p id="stamp3"></p>
            <p id="stamp4"></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="static/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am not finding other proper answer (as you can see I implemented an unnecessary complex package.json while trying to find a solution)

May someone help me understanding why I am not seeing the result of the async function printed to main.html after the submit button is clicked when the app is being deployed on Heroku?

many thanks!

Comment: can you give your code so that I can try on my heroku, async await worked fine on my heroku app. mabye problem is with your heroku configuration. github or discord `charchit#8198` id you want it to be private.

Comment: thank you! I'll be doing that!